# Differences between testing JavaScript and testing Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing

i was wondering if there is any difference between performing tests on JavaScript, or Ajax?

I understand that JavaScript is part of the Ajax equation, but is there any forms of execution differences when I am performing tests for JavaScript or JavaScript which is used to enable AJAX?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax means your code performs requests to the server, usually using the XMLHttpRequest object. If your test of that code involves a server, you may end up actually testing more server code then JavaScript. If you are fine with that, you can use a testing framework like [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)(part of the jQuery project, but doesn't require jQuery) or [YUI Test](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/test/#asynctests) that supports asynchronous tests, which are necessary here.

Otherwise you should replace the actual ajax request with a mock request that just returns some testdata, without ever performing an actual request. There are various solutions for that, but I need more context for any specific recommendation. Though, if you are using [jQuery's ajax module](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can leverage the xhr-option for replacing the XMLHttpRequest with a mock object.

Answer (score 0):

I think an important part of AJAX is the first A: Asynchronous.

In my (albeit small) experience with testing AJAX is that oftentimes you need to wait for something to happen: Wait for some text to appear on your html, wait for an image to disappear, wait for some style to be applied... I think this is one of the key differences between testing "regular" JavaScript code versus AJAX scripts.